# Java string split length

Tags: java, string, split

```
System.out.println("neon.mems.cmu.edu/people/".split("/").length); // output is 2
```

I was doing some url processing. To my surprise I just got the result above. I thought the number of elements could be the number of splitters plus one.

I didn't realize the last empty string(or just `null`) is cut off from the splitted array until now. I wonder if this is the case with every programming language.

Comment: It's a library decision - not part of the language at all. I wouldn't particularly *expect* consistency on this.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a constructive question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No that's not the case for every programming language and there is no universal specification so there is no reason it should be.

**Go**

```
a := strings.Split("neon.mems.cmu.edu/people/", "/")
fmt.Println(len(a)) // prints 3
```

**Javascript**

Type this in the console of your browser :

```
"neon.mems.cmu.edu/people/".split('/')
```

The result is

```
["neon.mems.cmu.edu", "people", ""]
```

What you should do when a match is empty isn't something obvious or inherent to the `split` concept. A proof of that is that old Internet Explorer versions [did remove those empty matches](http://xregexp.com/cross_browser/).

Comment: Good example. I'm convinced. Thanks.

Comment: `"neon.mems.cmu.edu/people/".split("/")[2]` cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

Comment: @Quoi I think you missed the "console of your browser" in my answer. This answer, as requested by OP who was wondering about other languages, shows a Javascript example.

Answer (score 1):

> why it is discarded empty string?

`String#split(regx)` internally call `String#split(regx,0)` which execute `Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);`  actually - [code snippet](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.split%28java.lang.CharSequence,int%29)

```
if (limit == 0)
        while (resultSize > 0 && matchList.get(resultSize-1).equals(""))
            resultSize--;
```

where empty string has been discarded from resultSize if limit is 0.

> How to get desired result?

`String#split(regx,limit)` use get desired result.

```
System.out.println("neon.mems.cmu.edu/people/".split("/",3).length);
```

Result :

```
 3
```

And about language specification I am agree with @dystroy

Comment: haha I like this trick. I can vary the length to anything I like through the `limit` parameter.